# Navigating inside a floating action button

Tags: java, android

I have added Main activity. I have a FAB button and i am trying to navigate to one of the fragments on click of the button. But I receive *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination XXXXX/galleryFragment is unknown to this NavController* Not sure what is the reason for the exception. I am new to android development please excuse my ignorance

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    Navigation.setViewNavController(fab, navController);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.galleryFragment);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `nav_graph` ?

Answer (score 1):

`Navigation.findNavController(view)` only works when the View is within the `NavHostFragment` (i.e., it is a view created by one of your fragments).

If your `FloatingActionButton` is outside of the `NavHostFragment` (such as in your activity's layout), then you need to use the same thing you're using in `onCreate()`: `Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)`:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.galleryFragment);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store the `navController` as a global variable, then don't use `Navigation.findNavController`, use `navController.navigate`.

```
NavController navController = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            navController.navigate(R.id.galleryFragment);
        }
    });
}
```